# Why do some metal oxides behave as n-type or p-type extrinsic semiconductors without adding a dopant?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, material-science, electronics

There are some metal oxides that are said to be extrinsic n-type and p-type semiconductors without having been doped. For example, $\mathrm{In_2O_3}$, $\mathrm{SnO_2}$ and $\mathrm{ZnO}$ are said to be n-type semiconductors, while $\mathrm{NiO}$, $\mathrm{Co_3O_4}$, $\mathrm{CuO}$ or $\mathrm{Cr_2O_3}$ are p-type semiconductors [[1](https://doi.org/10.3390%2Fs17102216),[2](https://doi.org/10.3390/s22041359)].

I have seen this statement in several papers and find it confusing since we define [extrinsic semiconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrinsic_semiconductor) (n-type and p-type) as those that have been doped in contrast to [intrinsic semiconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_semiconductor), which are those that haven't been doped.

What physical phenomenon allows some metal oxides to exhibit extrinsic semiconducting behavior without adding a dopant? Besides, what makes some undoped metal oxides behave like p-type extrinsic semiconductors whereas other metal oxides behave like n-type ones?

Comment: For ones I have a passing familiarity with, there are specific defects (say, oxygen vacancies) that occur at reasonable concentrations thermodynamically. Further, they introduce 'doping' levels into the gap. The net effect is that the "pure" (albeit not-perfectly-stoichiometric) material acts as if doped. The specifics of which defect and which levels it has determine what the net doping looks like.

Comment: It makes sense. However, why do those oxygen vacancies make some undoped metal oxides to be n-type whereas other metal oxides become p-type?

Comment: It isn't always an oxygen vacancy. For example, in Ga2O3 the gallium vacancy is an acceptor. As well, just what energy states a given defect level has will vary with the specifics of the band structure.

Comment: But why some metal oxides (such as ZnO) would tend to lose oxygens (becoming n-type semiconductors) and other metal oxides (such as Ga2O3) would tend to lose a metal atom (becoming a p-type semiconductor)?

Comment: That starts delving deep into the thermodynamics of the particular crystals. Particularly in the complex oxides (so, Ga2O3, not ZnO), each element has multiple different sites to sit on (octahedral vs tetrahedral Ga for example). Since the sites are not equivalent, the energetics of vacancy formation on each site will be different. More broadly, a preference on one side or the other of stoichiometry is quite common in binary phases, but the impact on electronic structure may not be so readily seen.

Comment: @user21390097 Note that dopants are not always of a particular type. This isnt some kind of outlier scenario. For example, silicon (as a dopant) can be either an n type or p type dopant depending on the semiconductor it is in. It can even be both in the same semiconductor! (Depending on concentration)

Answer (score 0):

I will restrict myself to the materials listed. NiO is a Mott-insulator not a semiconductor (even if some references give a bandgap < 4 eV). If you understand Mott-transition well (the insulating state appears with a non entirely full d-band due to the correlations), you can deduce approximately the tendancy towards p-type of these transition metals oxides compared to the other listed compound were the d orbitals are full and when there is no defects and impurities.

Some exceptions can be given as the effects of vacancies.